# About closed curves in a dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Let $F:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a vectory field $C^{k}$, $k\geq 1$. We considerer the system
$$x^{\prime} = F(x)$$

Now let $\gamma$ a closed simple curve $C^{1}$ invariant for the system. **I need to prove if $\gamma$ has no critical points, then $\gamma$ is a orbit for the system $F$.**

The truth is that the only attempt or idea that I have is by contradiction but I don't see so clearly either why this proposition occurs

EDIT: An invariant curve for the system is a curve such that for any initial condition on the curve the corresponding solution remains in the curve for all times (in its domain of definition)

Btw, an orbit is a solution that satisfies the ODE system.

Comment: Do you mean $\gamma$ or $F$?

Comment: Edit your post to include the definitions: What does it mean for $\gamma$ to be "invariant for the system," and what is an orbit?

Comment: ready the edit, I hope now you can understand

Comment: What does critical points have to,do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch for a solution that might work.

Look at a simpler case first: that is for a circle $S^1$. Suppose we have a $C^1$ flow defined on $S^1$. We can express this as an ODE using polar coordinates:
$$\dot\theta = f(\theta)$$
where $f$ is $C^1$ and $2\pi$-periodic. Then we can consider three cases.

1. $f(\theta_c)=0$ for some $\theta_c$
2. $f(\theta) > 0$ for all $\theta$
3. $f(\theta) < 0$ for all $\theta$

In the first case, there is a fixed point at $\theta = \theta_c$. For the second case, the flow is always moving counter-clockwise and the speed can be bounded below by some $m>0$ such that $f(\theta) \geq m$. This implies that circle is a periodic orbit. A similar argument shows we get a periodic orbit in the third case.

So if we have a flow defined on a circle, we either have a fixed point or the circle is a periodic orbit.

To solve for your case, you can reduce to the above argument by noting a) there is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism between $S^1$ and $\gamma$ and b) since $\gamma$ is invariant $F$ defines a flow restricted to $\gamma$.